# Nginx + php-fpm обрезает ответ

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

Ubuntu 16.04. Установил yandex odyssey 1.0rc1. Запустил и сразу при ответе от php nginx начал обрезать ответ от php. Проверили на стороне php, php не режет данные и отправляет все данные. Решили, что проблема в yandex odyssey, остановил, запустил pgbouncer. Результат такой же приходят срезанные данные на 2-3 байта. Собрка yandex odyssey производилась на сервере. Почему nginx обрезает ответ?

В коде php сами считаем content-length. Если его убрать, то все работает нормально. До этого ошибки не было и всё работало с установленным в коде content-length. content-length необходим.
Права на папки есть (проверено и для nginx и для php). Перестанавливал и nginx и php-fpm ничего не помогло.

Comment: В коде php сами считаем content-length. Если его убрать, то все работает нормально. До этого ошибки не было и всё работало с установленным в коде content-length. content-length необходим.

Comment: Значит считаете его вы совершенно неверно........ и скорее всего проблема в том, что контент на русском, а считаете функциями не предназначенными для мультибайтовых строк

Comment: вероятнее всего, вы неверно считаете content-length на стороне бекенда. например, перевод строки в конце документа/данных добавляется после того как вы посчитали значение content-length. я бы начал искать закономерность с вывода в лог nginx переменной $upstream_response_length (и, наверное, значения заголовка content-length тоже) и наблюдением того как вычисленный content-length отличается от upstream_response_length. всегда ли разница постоянна? откуда она?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если бы ваша гипотеза была верна, разница была бы больше упомянутых "2-3 байта". ну или гипотеза верна и в данных одна-две русских буквы или эмоджи )))

Comment: @nörbörnën вполне допускаю такой вариант)) типа буква "Х" )))